# Check if an Excel cell value is error (NaN, N/A, #ERROR, etc.)

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to make a function to deal with errors of cell values in Excel. When I run it I get an error because `IsError` function doesn't exist in VBScript.

```
Function errValue(j, pos)
    er=false
    ran = Mid(oSht.Cells(1, pos).Address, 2, InStr(2, oSht.Cells(1, pos).Address, "$") - 2)&j
    'ran is D17

    Set R = oSht.Range(ran)
    If IsError(R.Value) Then
        Select Case R.Value
            Case CVErr(xlErrValue)
                er=true
            Case CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
                er=truee
            Case CVErr(xlErrName)
                er=true
            Case Else
                er=true
        End Select
    End If
    errValue = er
End function
```

Is there another way?

Comment: [`Err`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf5ze0e(v=vs.84).aspx) is a built-in object in VBScript try changing your variable from `err` to something else.

Comment: Can you post the definition for the `IsError()` function you have referenced in the code snippet above? Also I see you've changed the variable name, can I suggest you should also use `Dim` to declare `er`, `ran` and `r` at the local scope level, as it stands they are global and accessible outside the `errValue()` function.

Comment: I changed err to er and the error is the same.

Comment: I have no definition for IsError() function. I found it while searching on Google; it's supposed to be for checking for error values on Excel cells, and I'm not really sure I can use it on a VBScript environment.

Comment: Sorry to bother you - but what are you trying to achive - why are you rebuilding this Function, when it is already available in your sheet? why don't you just use the "=ISERROR(D17)" in the cell?

Comment: There in lies the problem, `IsError()` is a built in function in Excel VBA not VBScript, the error is caused because VBScript doesn't know what `IsError()` is.

Comment: @Lankymart Thank you very much. Do you know any workaround to simulate this using VBScript? That would be very useful.

Comment: @therak I'm trying to create a script to check if the value I got from a cell from an Excel sheet is valid or not (I get a NaN error sometimes and I don't really know how to deal with it).

Comment: Think what you are trying to do is use [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/iserror.php)...unfortunately I don't know the VBScript equivalent.

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into your question. Post it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution the OP came up with herself:

```
Function errValue(j, pos)
  er = False
  ran = Mid(oSht.Cells(1, pos).Address, 2, _
        InStr(2, oSht.Cells(1, pos).Address, "$") - 2) & j
  Set R = oSht.Range(ran)

  If Not VarType(R.Value) <> vbError Then
    er = True
  End If

  errValue = er
End Function
```

which could be simplified to this:

```
Function errValue(j, pos)
  addr = oSht.Cells(1, pos).Address
  ran  = Mid(addr, 2, InStr(2, addr, "$") - 2) & j

  errValue = VarType(oSht.Range(ran).Value) = vbError
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`WorksheetFunction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object should allow you to use Excel functions from VBScript and VBA:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

...

If xl.WorksheetFunction.ISERROR(R.Value) Then
    Select Case R.Value
        Case CVErr(xlErrValue)
            er=true
        Case CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
            er=truee
        Case CVErr(xlErrName)
            er=true
        Case Else
            er=true
    End Select
End If
```

I don't have access to Excel right now, though, so I can't test.